# Responsive design with two pages in one on JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a mobile application with JQuery Mobile that is responsive design.

In other words, I want, in smartphone, that "page1.html" and "page2.html" are loaded in separed pages like that :

```
 _________              __________
|Page1    |             |Page2    |
|.html    |  on click   |.html    |
|         | <---------  |         |
|         |             |go to    |
|go to    | on click    |page1 btn|
|page2 btn| ----------> |         |
|_________|             |_________|
```

And, in tablets, I want that page1.html and page2.html are loaded in the same page like that :

```
-----------------------------
|Page1.html   | Page2.html   |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|----------------------------
```

How to do that with JQueryMobile ? I have try to $.mobile.loadpage(url) and $.mobile.changepage(url) but the problem is that the page is replaced and I need to have two pages in a single view for tablets.

Thanks per advance for your help.

Comment: You can't have two `data-role=page` in one view. You need to use media queries or check the screen size on `pageinit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its simple enough, like @Omar said, first of all use a single page template like this with 'data-role=page' denoting each page.

```
<body>
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="pageOne">
 <---header---->
 <--- content --->
 <---footer---->
 </div>
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="pageTwo">
 <---header---->
 <--- content --->
 <---footer---->
 </div>
```

Now, Jquery mobile will automatically show 'pageOne' on first load and hide 'pageTwo' and on navigating to 'pagetwo' will hide 'pageOne'.

After this you can write a css media query similar to this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 450px) {
   #pageOne{
    display:block;
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    postion:relative;
    }
   #pagetwo{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    padding-left: 2em;
    postion:relative;
    }
}
```

So if any with width greater than the mentioned width(450px) will have both the pages displayed side by side. Hope this helps. Here is a simple working sample I made.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwZpM/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, with the css media query, two pages are display in device < 450px width, and one page is display pages on device > 450px width. However, the two pages are layered. I don't know how to display one below the other, or side by side. Using float: left; for the pageOne and float: right; for the page two works on "classical" div but when the div has a "data-role="page", it doesn't works.

Comment: hey, please try making the width of the pages 50% and display: inline-block.. have made those changes in my answer.

Comment: Warning: the framework will only load the first page of a multipage document if loaded through ajax. so i think you'd need to access this page from elsewhere in your site with `data-ajax=false` (haven't tried it yet this is just based on my understanding)