# Checkout flow for jQuery mobile / tablet / desktop with knockout.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm trying to finally fix my custom shopping cart flow for mobile users by completely rearchitecting my site. I've chosen jQuery mobile for all my phone, tablet + desktop users.

The actual flow is fairly simple with payment selection (paypal or credit card), address input, payment input, confirmation of items..

I want the absolute best possible experience tailored nicely to the user's screensize.

For phone users I have three or four conceptual 'pages' of information that would map pretty nicely to a jQuery `ui-page`, however when in tablet I'd want to display two or more `ui-page` items at once - perhaps in a different order with pieces moved around.

Some immediate complications spring to mind:

- If I use jQuery pages and the user is on the desktop and he resizes the window to be small what should happen. What should happen in the reverse. Do I direct people to a completely different flow for small screens and larger ones or try to adapt realtime with css/javascript
- Consider if the user makes a mistake on a phone, or wants to change his cart. He will swipe left and I need that go to the last logical step he was on.
- I think trying to do tricky `float` css and [forcing hidden jQuery pages to be shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619108/responsive-design-with-two-pages-in-one-on-jquery-mobile) based on screen sizes will quickly come back and bite me.
- The rest of the site doesn't exist yet, for things like adding to cart and I want to figure out a strategy that will work nicely across the whole application.

My current best thinking is :

- Create two separate 'flows'. First for the phone which will use true jQuery pages. Second for the desktop which will be just one single page, or possibly two.
- I'm considering the first 'page' to be a fully responsive design that would expand out for the desktop but would only contain the first logical step for phone users. So I'd be hiding most of the page for small screens. Obviously only phone users could see the buttons that would navigate to the second and third `ui-page` items. This would result in duplicated fields across multiple pages, but I'm ok with that. It would give phone users the proper page experience and history management they'd expect and desktop users would only ever need to see the first `ui-page`.
- To get this to work nicely I'd need to use KnockoutJS with a single sitewide 'cart' model. This will make it easier to maintain two different flows, and also if I have the same content duplicated on multiple pages it will automagically update when the user switches pages.

Good idea / bad idea? Are there any good examples of a mobile checkout I can look at, or any jQuery/Knockout experts have suggestions or see any obvious dangers I should watch out for.